# Почему Visual Studio постоянно что-то грузит с серваков MS

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

 Я не понимаю почему IDE Visual Studio постоянно грузит символы с серваков MS. Хотя ничего я не меняю ХОБА и начинается 20 мин загрузка dll. Можно ли от этого как-нибудь избавится или загрузить их так чтоб он не перезагружал их постоянно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Загрузку символов можно огрничить в настройках Visual Studio на вкладке Debugging -> Symbols
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]